# generating random number based on points and chance in excel

Tags: excel, random, numbers

i have a excel file to choose a winner between my customers
[download excel file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/wbokwavfzddyy8b/New_Microsoft_Excel_Worksheet.xlsm/file)
but in 99 percent winners are top 2 customers with maximum points
can i make more chances for others with less point?

what i need is :
60 percent chances for top 5 percent of customers/
20 percent chances for next 20 percent of customers/
20 percent chances for next 75 percent of customers/
thanx

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number x between 0 and 1

```
Case x >= 0.4:
    Randomly pick from top 5% customers
Case x >= 0.2 and x < 0.4
   Randomly pick from mid 20 percent customers
Else
    Randomly pick from bottom customers
```

Comment: shuold i add this to macro ?

Comment: @aliro A macro will do, but you may be able to pull it off with formulas, although each time the worksheet is recalculated you get different people picked up.

Comment: can you explain more?i am newbie in excel

Comment: Did you ever do any programming?

Comment: i did not really